# Instantiate QML From C++

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, qml, qt5

I have 2 classes, MyApp and MyAppView. MyApp class will hold other classes and the implementation will be here. (you can call it Manager class or System class). MyAppView class only interacts with main.qml like it'll have lots of "Q_PROPERTY"ies. I think you understand the point. I don't want MyApp will have "Q_PROPERTY"ies.

The scenerio is as the following;

```cpp
//------------------------------------
//---------------------------main.cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "myapp.h"
#include "myappview.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

        qmlRegisterType<MyAppView>("org.myappview", 1, 0, "MyAppView");

        QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
        engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/main.qml")));
        if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
                return -1;

        MyApp myApp;

        return app.exec();
}



//------------------------------------
//---------------------------myappview.h
#include <QObject>

class MyAppView : QObject
{
        Q_OBJECT
        Q_PROPERTY(QString myString READ getMyString NOTIFY myStringChanged)

public:
        MyAppView();
        QString getMyString() { return m_myString; }
        void setMyString(QString newString)
        {
                m_myString = newString;
                emit myStringChanged;
        }

signals:
        void myStringChanged();

private:
        QString m_myString;
}



//------------------------------------
//---------------------------main.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

import org.myappview 1.0

Window {
        visible: true

        MyAppView {
                id: backend
        }

        Text {
                text: qsTr(backend.myString)
        }
}



//------------------------------------
//---------------------------myapp.h
#include <QObject>
#include "myappview.h"

class MyApp : QObject
{
        Q_OBJECT
public:
        MyApp();

private:
        MyAppView appView;
        void changeMyStringInAppView()
        {
                // This will automatically update main.qml
                appView.setMyString("This is new string");
        }
}
```

Also it is okay to reaching existing QML instance from MyApp, instead of instantiating QML from MyApp. So the main point is instantiating or reaching View class from Manager class so that I can control it easily. Maybe at some part, my logic is wrong. Please tell me if I am. I'm okay with all the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that the `MyAppView` of `MyApp` is different from the one created in QML, so if you update the `appView` text it will not be reflected in the `backend` text, so the solution is to expose an object from `MyApp` to QML with `setContextProperty()` and will call a function to establish the `MyAppView` created in QML (Keep in mind to create only one `MyApp` but you will have the same problem)

```
// myappview.h

#ifndef MYAPPVIEW_H
#define MYAPPVIEW_H

#include <QObject>

class MyAppView : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString myString READ getMyString NOTIFY myStringChanged)
public:
    explicit MyAppView(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent)
    {}
    QString getMyString() const { return m_myString; }
    void setMyString(const QString & newString)
    {
        if(m_myString != newString){
            m_myString = newString;
            emit myStringChanged();
        }
    }
signals:
    void myStringChanged();
private:
    QString m_myString;
};

#endif // MYAPPVIEW_H

// myapp.h

#ifndef MYAPP_H
#define MYAPP_H

#include "myappview.h"
#include <QObject>

class MyApp : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyApp(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent),
        appView(nullptr)
    {}
    Q_INVOKABLE void setAppView(MyAppView *value){
        appView = value;
    }
    void changeMyStringInAppView()
    {
       if(appView)
            appView->setMyString("This is new string");
    }
private:
    MyAppView *appView;
};

#endif // MYAPP_H

// main.cpp

#include "myapp.h"
#include "myappview.h"

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    qmlRegisterType<MyAppView>("org.myappview", 1, 0, "MyAppView");

    MyApp myapp;
    QTimer::singleShot(1000, &myapp, &MyApp::changeMyStringInAppView);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myapp", &myapp);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}

// main.qml

import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import org.myappview 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    MyAppView {
        id: backend
    }

    Text {
        text: qsTr(backend.myString)
    }
    Component.onCompleted: myapp.setAppView(backend)
}
```

Comment: Clean example. Thanks!